# What would happen if I touch two different pieces with each hand at same time?

Tags: rules

For example, I touch my king with the left hand and my queen with the right hand at the same time. Regarding the rules, I must move a touched piece, so what would happen in this case? Could I choose which piece to move? Would I lose the game automatically when doing such an action?

Is using both hands allowed at all? (e.g.: moving one piece with both hands).

As far as I know, at least in blitz, you must use the clock and move the pieces with the same hand, so what would happen there if you use both hands when moving a piece or touching two different pieces with each hand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [FIDE Laws of Chess](http://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=171&view=article), article §4.1:

> Each move must be made with one hand only.

So you are not allowed to make a move with both hands (this includes castling) and the arbiter can give you a penalty (§12.9) for this behaviour. IMHO, this should be a warning the first time you do it. In any case, because you touched the king and queen, you must make a move with either piece (§4.3):

> If the player having the move touches (...) one or more of his own pieces, he must move the first piece touched that can be moved.

Comment: Ty for the quick answer, maybe you can answer me a second question: Can opponent insist on the touch rule if you touch a piece by accident? (e.g. touching it with ellbow when reaching for a bottle...)

Comment: I'd say no, because §4.3 explicitly says *with the intention of moving or capturing*.

Comment: I was going to make a separate thread about this but seeing as you already answered here, I'll just ask you. What is the reason and history behind this rule ? It seems a bit ridiculous to get disqualified just because you touched another piece.

Comment: @Saikat: Both players are entitled to examine the board without visual distraction at any time, regardless of who is on move.  For a player on move to touch pieces would likely be a major distraction for his opponent, whether or not the action was intended as such.  In situations where touch-move rules would not apply, such as when one or both players is visually impaired, the two players use separate chessboards, but that would be a nuisance for normal games between sighted players.